# up/down button with min/max value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very new with jQuery/Javascript and I use this spinner. I don't want to use any plugin. But I want to ask how can I give a max. and min. value for Example min.value 0 and max.value 13. Input "number" doens't work in IE, because of i don't use it.
here is demo

http://jsfiddle.net/xg228/75/

```
   <form>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
     <td rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="number" value="1" style=" width: 50px; height:20px;               border:1px solid #dddddd ;" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value=" /\ " id="Up" onclick="this.form.number.value++;"></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type=button value=" \/ " id="Down"  onclick="this.form.number.value--;" ></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
          </form>

   #Up
    {
  font-size:7px;
 width:20px;
 height:12px;
 float:right; 
   margin-right:52px; 
    background-color:#dddddd;
    border:none; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #bababa;"
    }

  #Up:hover
 {
  background-color: #bababa;

   }

   #Up:active {
  outline: none;
    border: none;
     }

  #Up:focus {outline:0;}

   #Down
   {
  font-size:7px;
width:20px;
height:12px;
float:right; 
margin-right:52px; 
background-color:#dddddd;
border:none; 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #bababa;"
  }

   #Down:hover
 {
  background-color: #bababa;

  }

     #Down:active {
 outline: none;
  border: none;
    }

  #Down:focus {outline:0;}

  #Up:hover
   {
  background-color: #bababa;

 }
```

Comment: You can define min and max attribute in your html markup

Comment: Make a function, call it, add if statements! OR use HTML5 number input and be done.

Comment: type number/min and max work only in Chrome Safari Opera, because of i use type text with onclick ,but i want to give a min or max value, but i don't know how with this onclick ="this.form.number.value--;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little jQuery code, this can be accomplished.

I have set the `min` and `max` values in Javascript and I have removed the `onclick` handlers in HTML that you had.

This code has been tested in IE11.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/xg228/77)

Working Code Snippet:

**EDIT:** Disabled textbox to prevent user from entering invalid values.

```js
var min = 0,
    max = 13;

$("#Up").click(function(){
  if($("#input").val() < max && $("#input").val() >= min )
    $("#input").val(Number($("#input").val()) + 1);  // increment
});

$("#Down").click(function(){
  if($("#input").val() <= max && $("#input").val() > min )
    $("#input").val(Number($("#input").val()) - 1);  // decrement
});
```

```css
#Up
{
  font-size:7px;
  width:20px;
  height:12px;
  float:right; 
  margin-right:52px; 
  background-color:#dddddd;
  border:none; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bababa;"
}

#Up:hover
{
  background-color: #bababa;

}

#Up:active {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

#Up:focus {outline:0;}

#Down
{
  font-size:7px;
  width:20px;
  height:12px;
  float:right; 
  margin-right:52px; 
  background-color:#dddddd;
  border:none; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bababa;"
}

#Down:hover
{
  background-color: #bababa;

}

#Down:active {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

#Down:focus {outline:0;}

#Up:hover
{
  background-color: #bababa;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"><input type="text" name="number" value="1" style=" width: 50px; height:20px; border:1px solid #dddddd ;" id="input" disabled /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value=" /\ " id="Up" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type=button value=" \/ " id="Down" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: i can just type 25 in the box, and it will not be reduced or cleared. You can prevent this by adding readonly to the text box.

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl That can be restricted by disabling the textbox. The valued can still be updated in the disabled textbox. Please checkout the updated answer.

Comment: @RahulDesai yup, just as i mentioned readyonly will work too ;) i +1ed your answer ;)

Comment: @user123456 Please checkout the updated answer. I have disabled the functionality of entering a value so as to prevent the user from entering invalid values.